# Making a 2 dimensional list/matrix with different number of columns for each row

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, numpy, arraylist

I would like to make a list or matrix that has a known number of rows(3), but for each row the number of elements will be different.
So it could look something like this:

```
[[4, 6, 8],
[1, 2, 3, 4],
[0, 2, 3, 4, 8]]
```

Each row will have a known maximum of elements(8).

So far I have tried the following:

```
Sets1=np.zeros((3,8))

for j in range(3):
Sets1[0,:]=[i for i, x in enumerate(K[:-1]) if B[x,j]==1 or B[x+1,j]==1]
```

I want this because I want to have a list for each j in range(3) over which I can do a for loop and add constraints to my ILP.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Final expected output for the given sample?

Comment: You shouldn't call that a matrix because matrix is a rectangular array of numbers. It's just a 2D array.

Comment: Edit: Never mind I have figured it out.. I just wanted a list of lists. A got by creating an empty list and then just appending each list with the list I needed. Thanks though!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of what your code should look like:

```
from random import *

myMatrix = [
    [],
    [],
    []
]

elementsNums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] # possible length of each list in the matrix
elements = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] # random values in each list in the matrix


def addElements(Num, List, Matrix):
    count = 0

    a = choice(Num) #length of first list in matrix
    Num.remove(a) # removing to prevent same length lists in matrix

    b = choice(Num) # length of second list in matrix
    Num.remove(b)

    c = choice(Num) # length of third list in matrix

    nums = [a, b, c]

    for x in nums: # iterating through each list (a, b, c)
        for i in range(x): # placing x number of values in each list
            Matrix[count].append(choice(List)) # adding the values to the list
        count += 1 # moving to the next list in the matrix


addElements(elementsNums, elements, myMatrix)
print(myMatrix)
```